# trying to build an image locally from cloned repo and getting this error

Tags: docker, docker-build

```
docker build -t max-audio-embedding-generator .
[+] Building 1.9s (6/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for quay.io/codait/max-base:v1.4.0                                                                                                                              1.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                   0.7s
 => => transferring context: 6.04MB                                                                                                                                                          0.6s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM quay.io/codait/max-base:v1.4.0@sha256:1f09c52c5461b4a13b3a2e6166acac5165596a6e3f65b5c168a880cd4ac6bebe                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [2/6] RUN wget -nv --show-progress --progress=bar:force:noscroll https://max-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/max-audio-embedding-generator/1.0.0/assets.tar.gz --output-document=assets/a  0.7s
------
 > [2/6] RUN wget -nv --show-progress --progress=bar:force:noscroll https://max-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/max-audio-embedding-generator/1.0.0/assets.tar.gz --output-document=assets/assets.tar.gz &&   tar -x -C assets/ -f assets/assets.tar.gz -v && rm assets/assets.tar.gz:
#5 0.554 wget: unable to resolve host address ‘max-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud’
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget -nv --show-progress --progress=bar:force:noscroll ${model_bucket}/${model_file} --output-document=assets/${model_file} &&   tar -x -C assets/ -f assets/${model_file} -v && rm assets/${model_file}]: exit code: 4`
```

trying to build an image locally from cloned repo
and getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and format your error messages accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> `wget: unable to resolve host address ‘max-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud’`

I don't believe that domain is valid anymore, but a [github issue](https://github.com/IBM/MAX-Audio-Embedding-Generator/issues/53) points out that you should change the `model_buckets` arg to `https://codait-cos-max.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/max-audio-embedding-generator/1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

It can't resolve host "max-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud". So you need a correct DNS server to know how to reach the host, or if you know how what is its IP then to add it in your `hosts`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).